# How to use Flask to Display Data From Print

Tags: python, flask

I have this python code that I am trying to display data on static page 
using flask instead of console.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from private import private, private, private
optimizeit = get_optimizeit(web.site, private.private)
optimizeit.load_data_from_CSV("/path.../to..cvs.csv")
data = optimizeit.get_data_by_name('somename')
data = optimizeit.data[0]  
data.max_exposure = 0.5
generatedata = optimizeit.optimizeit(4)
for datafield in generatedata:
    print (datafield)
```

Where print I want to print this to simple flask page. I tried few things and I just can't think of way of doing it best way.

EDIT: What I tried

```
from __future__ import print_function
import flask
from private import private, private, private
import time
app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/sitea')
def index():
    def inner():
        optimizeit = get_optimizit(website.site12, private.someprivate)
        optimizer.load_players_from_CSV("/mypath to csv.../.csv") #import csv 
        data = optimizeit.datas[0]  #optimize that data
        data.max_exposure = 0.5 #set some exposure to that data 
        data_generator = optimizeit.optimizeit(4)
        for datalive in datalive_generator:
            return datalive
    return flask.Response(inner(), mimetype='text/html')  # text/html is required for most browsers to show the partial page immediately

app.run(debug=True)
```

EDIT 2: THIS WORKED!

```
from __future__ import print_function
import flask
from private import private, private, private
import time
app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/sitea')
def index():
    def inner():
        optimizeit = get_optimizit(website.site12, private.someprivate)
        optimizer.load_players_from_CSV("/mypath to csv.../.csv") #import csv 
        data = optimizeit.datas[0]  #optimize that data
        data.max_exposure = 0.5 #set some exposure to that data 
        data_generator = optimizeit.optimizeit(4)
        for datalive in datalive_generator:
            yield '%s<br/>\n' % datalive
    return flask.Response(inner(), mimetype='text/html')  # text/html is required for most browsers to show the partial page immediately
```

Comment: Have a look at the basic example at the very top of the front page of the Flask docs: http://flask.pocoo.org/  You could basically put exactly that code in a single "view" and return the data from that view.  You'll probably get more traction if you rephrase your question by showing what you *did* try and what specific problem(s) you encountered.

Comment: Thanks.
Ill edit as to what I tried.newbie here :)

Comment: Done.. Check it out..

Comment: Thanks.  You didn't mention in what way it didn't work though--a good question contains not only what you tried, but what outcome you were hoping for and what outcome you obtained instead. But I think I can probably tell you.  Your `inner()` function ends with `for datalive in datalive_generator: return datalive`.  That means the function returns just the first element in `datalive_generator` and then returns.  You probably meant `yield datalive` here.

Comment: It was just a blank page.. I am still tryying to figure out some def indents etc.. I know this is bit complex for my test of python but ... you know :) trying to get it to work. You are correct.. What I want to return is the datalive_generator

With print statement I would just do 
print(datalive) and generated data would come from datalive_generator

Comment: Try `yield` there instead.  It's probably all you're missing.

Comment: Thank you sooo much! I got it working 
            yield '%s<br/>\n' % datalive
    return flask.Response(inner(), mimetype='text/html')

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
    for datalive in datalive_generator:
        return datalive
```

this just returns the first item in `datalive_generator` and then exits the function, never to return.  You probably meant `yield datalive`.  This way it will continue streaming output to the response.  In the meantime you'll want to do some search into the difference between generators and normal functions in Python.